# Closure and induced subspace topology of this space?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

For the basis given here [Did I show that this is a basis for a topology on $X=\Bbb N \cup \{-1/n | n \in \Bbb N \}$ correctly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285482/did-i-show-that-this-is-a-basis-for-a-topology-on-x-bbb-n-cup-1-n-n-in) I want to understand if I'm doing a few more things correctly :

1) The topology generated by the basis is the set containing all unions of basis elements , therefore it's $\tau= \{\cup((a,\infty)\cup(-1,b)\cup(c,d))|a,b,c,d \in X, c<d, b>-1\}$.

2) The limit points of $\Bbb N$ are $\Bbb N\cup \{-1,n\}$ as every point in 
in the space will belong to a some set which spans infinitely outward and so the intersection between that set and $\Bbb N$ will be non empty and contain infinitely many other points, similarly for $\{-1/n\}$ the limit points are $\Bbb N\cup \{-1,n\}$, so the boundary of $\Bbb N\cup\{-1/n\}$ is $\Bbb N\cup\{-1/n\}$

3) finally I want show this topology and the subspace topology induced from the real line are the same , but I really don't see how this is, as it seems to me that $\tau$ will still be rays and intervals in the subspace topology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology is { $\cup$K : K subset base }.

The only limit point is 0.
The boundary of X as a subspace is empty.
The boundary of X as a subset of R is X.

Yes, X is a subspace of R.
Show that that the open sets of X are of the form X $\cap$ U for some open subset U of R.
The linear order topology for N $\cup$ { -1/2n : n positive integer } is an example of a topology that's not a subspace of R, even though it is homeomorphic to X.

Comment: If the definition here of $\Bbb N$ is  $\Bbb N=\Bbb Z^+$ then $X$ with the order topology is NOT a subspace of  $\Bbb R$ because then $1$ is the lub in $X$ of $\{y\in X:y<1\}$ so in the order topology on $X$  the point $1$ is in the closure of $\{-1/n:N\in \Bbb N\}.$